# Making this function recursive on an array

Tags: php

I have got the following array:

```json
{
  "slider": {
    "effect": {
      "el": ".custom-class"
    },
    "custm": "slider",
    "arrowsEnabled": "1",
    "pagination.el": ".swiper-pagination"
  }
}
```

Any key which has got the dot notation I need use this function on:

```php
function convertDotToArray($array)
{
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $dots = explode(".", $key);
        if (count($dots) > 1) {
            $last = &$newArray[ $dots[0] ];
            foreach ($dots as $k => $dot) {
                if ($k === 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                $last = &$last[$dot];
            }

            $last = $value;
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

However due to the only `key` I have got being 2 level deep that function isn't applying to the `pagination.el` key. I need make this function recursively go over any array passed into it so that no matter how deep the keys are they are converted, so my array should turn into this:

```json
{
  "slider": {
    "effect": {
      "el": ".custom-class"
    },
    "custm": "slider",
    "arrowsEnabled": "1",
    "pagination": {
      "el": ".swiper-pagination"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So? What is your question? Also, test driven development, just a suggestion.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that function is only doing a 1 dimensional array, so the key `pagination.el` is being missed. I need to make it multi dimensional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use recursivity:

```php
function convertDotToArray($array)
{
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = convertDotToArray($value);
        }

        $parts = explode('.', $key);
        $pointer = &$newArray;

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $pointer = &$pointer[$part];
        }

        $pointer = $value;
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

**Example:**

```php
<?php
$jsonData = <<<EOD
{
  "slider": {
    "effect": {
      "el": ".custom-class"
    },
    "custm": "slider",
    "arrowsEnabled": "1",
    "pagination.el.el.el": ".swiper-pagination",
    "deep.deep":{"deep.deep":"deep"}
  }
}
EOD;

$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
print_r(convertDotToArray($data));
```

gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [slider] => Array
        (
            [effect] => Array
                (
                    [el] => .custom-class
                )

            [custm] => slider
            [arrowsEnabled] => 1
            [pagination] => Array
                (
                    [el] => Array
                        (
                            [el] => Array
                                (
                                    [el] => .swiper-pagination
                                )

                        )

                )

            [deep] => Array
                (
                    [deep] => Array
                        (
                            [deep] => Array
                                (
                                    [deep] => deep
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did do that exact same thing but it didn't work, I can see you modified other parts of the function though which is probably why it didn't work for me.